# How to know the linux distribution I have?

Tags: linux, debian

I run a debian 7. When I launch

> cat /etc/debian_version

I have

> 7.7

and when I launch

> cat /etc/issue

the response is

> Debian GNU/Linux 7.6

Do I run 7.7 or 7.6?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
lsb_release -a
```

or

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```

or

```
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: As I said `cat /etc/debian_version` gives `7.7` but `cat /etc/issue` gives `Debian GNU/Linux 7.6`. And `lsb_release: command not found`